# how do you keep leading zeros in a csv file using python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, openpyxl

Lets say my csv file looks something like this:

```
acc_num,pincode
023213821,23120
002312727,03131
231238782,29389
008712372,00127
023827812,23371
```

when I open this file in excel , it removes the leading zeros , but here I need to keep them . This is how it looks when i open it in excel

```
acc_num,pincode
23213821,23120
2312727,3131
231238782,29389
8712372,127
23827812,23371
```

I tried converting this into a string but it still shows it without 0 (but its a string now)
I tried using the astype() function from pandas but there's no point in using it

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is this an Excel question or a Python question? As an aside, Pandas’ `.read_csv()` allows you to specify the dtype of each column, so an `astype()`shouldn’t be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Did you format the cells in the excel document as 'text', so that when you open it in excel it displays the leading zeros, then when you bring it into Python, ensure you're bring it in and storing as a string, as python3 does not allow leading zeros in ints.